# What setting hides the side panel whenever VS Code opens?

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS Code has a Side Panel that includes Problems, Output, Debug Console, and Terminal.

What, if any, setting will always hide the Side Panel when we open VS Code?

I appreciate that we can toggle it via

- mouse `View` | `Appearance` | `Show Side Panel`
- keyboard <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>.

How, though, can we tell VS Code always to hide the Side Panel when VS Code opens?

[image: View > Appearance > Show Side Panel in VS Code]